# Cloth repels and glitches through object

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

So, as I referenced in an earlier question, I made a character with hair made of cloth. I try and animate this hair, and I have managed to pin it in place, and make it look right, but when I start the animation, the cloth seems to almost push away from itself and the head it is attached to. I did not add any force field modifiers, and I am wondering why it won't just lay flat. First it bounces away from everything, and then it hovers a little bit away.
Is there a setting that makes cloth try and hover over other folds of cloth, and/or objects?
I want to figure out how to get the cloth to just sit on her head, without bouncing or constricting or pushing.
Maybe soft body? I don't know the difference between them...

[image]
[image]

Comment: That should be the cloth self collision: if you need it, to avoid the jump, the inital mesh parts are not "in contact"...

Comment: ....Hmm. The cloth collision and self collision is set to the smallest distance. But it still kinda "floats" away from the object and tends to glitch out and get stuck. Maybe its not pushing its self away, but its pulling itself away? I don't know what setting that would be though.. bounciness? It seems to pull itself together now, and deflate almost, so its not as big. I want it to stay the same shape, but move and wave like cloth. Or like hair that is made of giant pixels :/

Answer (score 0):

try this file... maybe you get some hints
[image]

I tried to separate well the unpinned geometry (exagerating a bit but...) and subdivided also the hair so they get a better cloth structure

Comment: I'm not sure that helped.... It was interesting, but my goal to to get the hair to connect to the head, but not bounce off.
... Mostly, It needs to act the same as if it were just clothes. Almost like a dress or a skirt even, the cloth hanging down and swishing, or swirling then the object moves, and not be perpetually pushing away from itself and glitching out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the vertex groups on the hair because when I remove all but the "hairtop" (which is used for pinning ) then the simulation works fine.

But then the hair doesnt follow the armature...

Comment: Hmm, that might be it. The cloth is made from another rig that I used as a basis, so I'll try that out.